# Worklight SQL Adapter Idle Timeout

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Is there a way to create and idle time out in the sql adapter.

Right now im getting java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe exceptions when the connection has been idle and the DB has cut it off.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Adapter simply rides on top of your jdbc pool. Try configuring idle connection properties for it, e.g. for Tomcat - http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html (search for "idle")

Comment: But does this still hold true if you are using the jdbc connection in the adapter descriptor instead of the jndi

Comment: The Worklight JDBC connection pool implementation is not meant for production use and does not contain the same amount of control that is available through JNDI configuration.